# Magento 2.3 Backup failed Error received from server

Tags: magento2.3, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.1

I want to upgrade magento from 2.3 > 2.3.1

my system running on google cloud servers using bitnami

I have registered my domain on cloudflare to get the ssl

at first upgrade attempt on third section to create Backup (after Readiness Check), I had this error 
[image]

where after checking the install log file I find that all backups created excepts for database stucks on

```
DB backup is creating ...
```

list of backup files (I attempt multiple times):

[image]

and when I was checking the browser console I found that the error was :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 524 ()
```

So I find that the issue is related to wait above 100 seconds and related to cloudflare 
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171926-Error-524-A-timeout-occurred

So I cut it connection and use the External IP for my VM in google cloud directly (Of course I changed the settings on store configuration to use the ip address)

so that I don't rely to cloudflare nor domain and connect direct to google cloud VM

2nd attempt to upgrade to 2.3.1 using the IP address I faced this issue:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"index.php/maintenance/index","data":{"disable":true},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}
```

[image]

please, How can I resolve this issue ?

**{UPDATE}**
After changing permission on Var and created backups and pass to system upgrade
the backup stopped and gives me Rollback button.

[image]

Console Log:

[2019-04-01 10:06:03 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has started
Enabled maintenance mode

```
[2019-04-01 10:06:03 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has been successfully completed
[2019-04-01 10:06:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has started
Changed cache status:
config: 1 -> 0
layout: 1 -> 0
block_html: 1 -> 0
collections: 1 -> 0
reflection: 1 -> 0
db_ddl: 1 -> 0
compiled_config: 1 -> 0
eav: 1 -> 0
customer_notification: 1 -> 0
config_integration: 1 -> 0
config_integration_api: 1 -> 0
full_page: 1 -> 0
config_webservice: 1 -> 0
translate: 1 -> 0
vertex: 1 -> 0

[2019-04-01 10:06:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has been successfully completed
```

in Network I found this is the isse

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 131278

Varnish cache server
```

Where now the full website is not working!

I followed the instruction on Bitnami to configure `varnish`

https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/magento/configuration/configure-varnish/

but it doesn't work and the full website is down

Also `bin/magento {command}` neither `bin/magento {command}` it was not working, there was a problem with composer somehow after the website went down

so I Updated composer and it downoaded and installs all components

then when I try `bin/magento {command}` neither `bin/magento {command}` it stuck and doesnt display any thing so I had to terminated using `CTRL+ X`

It tooks long time to stop by it self with this error message
[image]

Now I cannot Rollback nor do anything.

I am using Bitnami on google cloud. Is there a way to

- download the 3 backups files from this VM,
- then install fresh Magento on another VM
- then upload the backups files
- Then Rollback the backups files on the new fresh magento

does it going to install the theme again or I should upload its files the do Rollback?

how can I restart the website and restore the backup files?
How to upgrade correctly?

Comment: check `var` folder permisson https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: @RakeshDonga Thank you, it pass and created backups, but on system upgrade it stopped and give me Rollback button (But actually giving me Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed) Varnish cache server

Comment: yes i know that

Comment: here guide to how to restore ref: https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-perform-magento-2-rollback/  ,  i have some day ago restore this way i have same issue

Comment: @RakeshDonga when I try `bin/magento {command}` neither `bin/magento {command}` it stuck and doesnt display any thing so I had to terminated using `CTRL+ X`